# Unicode characters do not have correct width in the terminal

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, fonts, unicode, emoji

This doesn't happen with all unicode characters, but does happen with scissors: ✂️
It seems to be a problem independent of font as I've tried multiple different monospace fonts, patched and unpatched with "Nerd fonts" (I did try system default monospace)

neovim:
[image: scissors emoji in neovim] scissors overlap the next character in neovim

vscode:
[image: scissors emoji rendered in vscode] uses a different character / emoji set, but it looks like vscode renders differently, as there is no overlap

gedit:
[image: scissors emoji is rendered correctly] renders as I'd expect: no overlap

terminal:
[image: scissors emoji in the terminal]
has the same problem as in neovim

github: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/dotfiles/blob/75ad3987e4eaa550e7dfb70a37ffe2b756594bd9/home/scripts/unme

[image: github rendering of the scissors emoji]
GitHub in Firefox looks correct

Is there a way to configure the terminal to have consistent emoji/unicode width/rendering?

---

Additional info, per requests of commenters:

```bash
❯ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

my .bashrc is nearly empty and only has

```bash
[ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash

export PNPM_HOME="/home/nullvoxpopuli/.local/share/pnpm"
export PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
```

and `~/.fzf.bash` (which I think is default? / automatically generated for me?)

```bash
# Setup fzf
# ---------
if [[ ! "$PATH" == */home/nullvoxpopuli/.fzf/bin* ]]; then
  export PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}/home/nullvoxpopuli/.fzf/bin"
fi

# Auto-completion
# ---------------
[[ $- == *i* ]] && source "/home/nullvoxpopuli/.fzf/shell/completion.bash" 2> /dev/null

# Key bindings
# ------------
source "/home/nullvoxpopuli/.fzf/shell/key-bindings.bash"
```

my terminal has "Run command as a login shell" checked in preferences, so I use `~/.bash_profile` instead, and that file is here: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/dotfiles/blob/main/home/.bash_profile
(and is quite large / pulls in some other custom scripts)

**However**,  I confirm that commenting out the entirety of `~/.bash_profile` and after opening a new terminal, the problem persists.

Comment: No problem here in gnome-terminal or vim. Scissors character takes two spaces.

Comment: hmm -- I'm using gnome-terminal. I wonder if it could be my font. I'm using `DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono`  in my terminal. 
what font are you using?

Comment: added locale, bashrc, and link to bash_profile

Comment: updated with fzf.bash!

Comment: how would anything in my bash_profile affect how the terminal renders text tho?

Comment: oh, I just commented out my entire .bash_profile and opened a new terminal, and the problem persists -- so... I don't think it's at all related to my .bash_profile

Comment: I checked on my system today and I get the same of what you describe ... It is a rendering issue not related to fonts as much as it is related to that special Unicode emoji ... Unicode characters/emojis come in different widths/spaces (single or double) ...  gnome-terminal appears to have this problem of not correctly accounting for some double space characters ... a simple solution is to add an extra space after that character like so `dev="/✂️ /"`

Comment: Please run this example `printf "|-|--|--|--|\n|\u2714|\u274c|\u270c|\u270c |\n^-^--^--^--^\n"` and compare how `u270c` needs an added space `u270c ` to be printed correctly while the character `u274c` is printed correctly although it is a double width like `u270c` ... It's just a matter of Unicode support.

Comment: So how do I improve unicode support in my terminal?  is there anything I can do? does gnome-terminal need a bug reported? or.. would they care? 

Comment: gnome-terminal depends on [many components](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-terminal) among which [libcairo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libcairo2) which is the rendering engine/component …. So I would say a limitation rather than a bug … unfortunately AFAIK there is nothing you can do in this regard unless if you are willing to experiment with [other terminal emulators](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators/) to see if any of them renders those unicode characters correctly.

Comment: Found the code -- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/tree/master -- I'll open an issue and see where that goes

Comment: reported here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/issues/573

Comment: In terminal it's only a graphical representation of a character. Different font is used render emojis, most likely Noto Color Emoji. Does it overlaps with the text variation selector appended \ufe0e at the end  `printf "\u2702\ufe0e"`? This is \u2702 with emoji presentation selector \ufe0e to force emoji `printf "\u2702\ufe0f"`

Comment: Btw, I remember I used pango to render images from emoji with imagemagick.
`convert -list format | grep -i pango
    PANGO* PANGO     r--   Pango Markup Language (Pangocairo 1.46.2)`
The vommand was `convert -background transparent -pointsize 90 'pango:✂️' scissors.png` Most likely this library is used for rendering emojis [PangoCairo](https://docs.gtk.org/PangoCairo/). Yes [gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/-/tree/main/pango](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/-/tree/main/pango)

Comment: Double-width Unicode characters will usually pose challenges with some terminal emulators. My suggestion is either to find a hack that makes it work for you, or only use single-width characters (if it needs to be compatible across multiple platforms).

Comment: Nice and prompt reply from the cairo team ... I had a chance to test with pango and it appears it's not a problem there as well ... tried `pango-view --font="Ubuntu Mono 24" --text='dev="/✂️/"'` and it rendered correctly ... Mmmm are you thinking what I'm thinking? :) ... I'm thinking gnome-terminal's implementation of those libraries.

Comment: After all this investigation, I think it’s worth a bug report to the gnome-terminal team (most likely it’s a bug in gnome-terminal’s implementation of those tow libraries) … I have to say, however, I am impressed by your enthusiasm and zeal following the root cause of this issue … I suggest you document what’s in the comments in an answer for posterity as I think it will be a valuable resource about text layout and rendering in gnome-terminal. Meanwhile, although chances are little, I hope someone will come up with a robust solution.

Comment: Reported here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7907

Hopefully someone sees it 

Comment: Please see `gedit /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz` ... it's the Unicode database/standard ... search in it for the codes mentioned in @МилошПавловић [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351278/unicode-characters-do-not-have-correct-width-in-the-terminal#comment2457287_1351278) `u2702`, `ufe0e` and `ufe0f` ... look at their description in that file ... It will help you write a canonical and more precise answer ... I am looking forward to reading it.

Comment: The issue is in the Vte Terminal widget [https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte). Not in gnome-terminal. Gnome terminal sets the cell size but Vte doesn't have a mechanism to expand individual cells if the glyph is bigger.

Comment: @МилошПавловић I expanded the cells with `dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/cell-width-scale 2.0` and get what you mean `2.0`(double cell) but, it's a gnome-terminal issue either ways ...  vte developers seem aware of this issue and explain how they handle it here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/doc/ambiguous.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adjust this setting in GNOME Terminal *Edit* -> *Preferences*.

[image: GNOME Terminal Preferences]

Comment: changing that to `2` *does* solve the alignment of the emojis -- however, all the other text is now very spread out -- which isn't great -- a bit worse off, I think